# PHP Notice errors and page load time

Tags: php

I am a php newb and I don't have a clear answer for this.

To what extent do PHP "Notice" errors affect load time?

Ty

Comment: explain the question properly

Comment: Other than an immeasurably miniscule amount of time spent writing to the error log for disk IO (on a small site anyway), they won't affect load time.  They should be considered _programming errors_ however, and should be eliminated!  If your code is issuing `E_NOTICE`s for undefined vars and indices (which is most common), it's usually an indication of sloppy coding that should fixed up.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Well, if this creates Megabytes of output, I'd say the load time in the browser is affected by that, especially with a GPRS modem.

Comment: @jhonraymos: I would say that was pretty clear...

Comment: @hakre Indeed, I guess, but if Megabytes of E_NOTICE are being sent down to the browser with display_errors on, the load time is the last of the dev's worries...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Maybe it's not obviously visible becuase hidden in some `<script>` tag or so. you never know ;)

Comment: @hakre - you're extrapolating *way* too much from this question. hehe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notice usually is logged to a file, so it involves I/O activity. In the worst case scenario however, the file will just consume the entire free space at HDD which effectivly will block your web site. Other than this, the performance decrease is usually negligible - there are a lot of things that are becoming bottleneck sooner than the notices.

Comment: @hakre that's what I'm saying :)

Answer (score 0):

They do not affect load time in any meaninful way.

However:

1. Notices are there to warn you of potentially bad coding practices and/or possible errors. You should write your code to avoid causing them.
2. On a production web site, you should disable error message output -- not because of any performance issues, but simply because having errors display on your site doesn't look very professional, and may give hackers clues about how to attack your system.

Answer (score 0):

Well, notices being spit out onto the page will result in more data being sent to the client's browser. So it could increase loading times for your visitors. For example, if you have notices that are occurring inside a large loop, this may add a great amount of unneeded data.

Server-side, I'd doubt that some simple I/O logging will cause any noticeable effects, unless you're getting an insane amount of traffic.

Lastly - notices are usually a sign that something isn't quiet right... Whether or not the problems that are causing these notices are contributing to a larger load time is anyone's guess.